# Trying to create a circle with star in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a complete circle with progress animation in css only with star rotating around it.

here is an example with svg animation. trying to create the same in CSS.

https://codepen.io/kapo09/pen/GRjxVqN

here is my code

```
}
  .lds-ring {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .lds-ring div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 25px solid #14213D;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: lds-ring 2.2s cubic-bezier(0.9, 0, 0.3, 0) infinite;
    border-color: #14213D transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  .lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
  }
  .lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -0.85s;
  }
  .lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: -0.65s;
  }
  .lds-ring div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: -0.45s;
  }
  .lds-ring div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: -0.30s;
  }
  .lds-ring div:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: -0.0s;
  }

  @keyframes lds-ring {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(105deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(460deg);
```

here is html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="circle-orbit-container">
    
        <!-- <div id="inner-orbit">
        </div> -->
        <div id="inner-orbit" class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: codepen link invalid

Comment: Honestly, SVG is a much better option here. Trying to wedge this in with CSS is unnecessary.